# Unable to Execute Automation tests in opera browser

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I try to use opera browser with selenium ,on running the scripts browser get launched but no tests are running in the browser instead a error popups. I am using operachromium driver with opera version 40  [image]

below is the code to create opera driver instance:

```
System.setProperty("os.name","windows");
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "path to operachromiumdriver");
driver = new ChromeDriver(); 
driver.get("http://google.com");
```

Can any one help me on this.

Comment: Wrong [driver](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24719270/selenium-webdriver-and-opera-driver) possibly. What version of Opera/Chrome/OS?

Comment: Opera version is 40,os is windows 8 and driver used is operachromium driver

Comment: And what happens when you call the exe in Cmdline?