# Is selenium automation in Opera browser possible using nightwatchJS?

Tags: selenium, automation, opera, nightwatch.js

I'm trying automation in Opera browser, but it's not working.

I got the below error message:

'Unable to create new service: OperaDriverService\nBuild

Here is my nightwatch.json code for opera:

```
"local-opera": {
      "launch_url": "http://localhost",
      "selenium_host": "127.0.0.1",
      "selenium_port": 4444,
      "silent": true,
      "output": true,
      "screenshots": {
        "enabled": false,
        "path": ""
      },
      "skip_testcases_on_fail": false,
      "desiredCapabilities": {
        "browserName": "opera",
        "javascriptEnabled": true,
        "acceptSslCerts": true,
        "operaOptions": {
          "binary": "C:/Users/userName/AppData/Local/Programs/Opera/launcher.exe"
        }
      }
    }
```

I am able to automate testing of my app in Chrome, Firefox, Edge and IE but I only find a problem with Opera.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26813266/5962966