# How to control webpage by Selenium on Python?

Tags: python, selenium

I'm working on a web page and I want to interact with it. I believe Selenium is the best option but I have no idea how to use it.

The only step I have taken is

`pip install selenium`

I'm getting errors like

> web driver not defined

The Selenium documentation is difficult to understand. My default browser is Opera.

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Opera()
driver.get('https://www.google.co.in/search?client=opera&q=google&sourceid=opera&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8')
```

Answer (score 0):

A driver is required in order for Selenium to know how to interact with the browser - see [this section of the documentation](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/installation.html#drivers).

Comment: Ok but where to place the webdriver for opera ?

Comment: @Naveen It is all written in the docs. just click the link and read the text

Comment: More information specifically for the Opera driver can be found on the [Github page](https://github.com/operasoftware/operaprestodriver) and in this [previous StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24719270/selenium-webdriver-and-opera-driver)

Answer (score 0):

As you have mentioned you already have:

- pip install selenium

Now, you need to downloaded the latest *OperaChromiumDriver* from [operasoftware / operachromiumdriver](https://github.com/operasoftware/operachromiumdriver/releases) and place it any where within your system. Finally, you need to pass the *Key* **executable_path** along with the *Value* referring to the absolute path of the *OperaDriver* as an argument while initializing the *WebDriver* and *WebBrowser* as follows :

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Opera(executable_path=r'C:\path\to\operadriver.exe')
driver.get('https://www.google.co.in/search?client=opera&q=google&sourceid=opera&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8')
```

> You can find a relevant discussion in [Unable to launch Opera using Python Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59815011/unable-to-launch-opera-using-python-selenium/59815127#59815127)

Comment: I tired with chrome but the page is not opening i'm getting error like this:
```DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:60400/devtools/browser/12414d7b-91c7-43fa-be4f-399a471969f1``` 

how to fix this ? And i tired with opera as you said but i'm getting error binary location not found

Comment: @Naveen Did you check the relevant discussion I have added as a reference?